# SVN setting permissions on checked in files

Tags: svn

I have a subversion repository which manages the contents of a linux directory. From inside a working copy I do this

```
> ls -l ./bin

-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   62 Jul  8 14:19 cmd_1.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 2234 Jul  8 19:37 cmd_2.sh*

> chmod a+x ./bin/cmd_1.sh

-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user   62 Jul  8 14:19 cmd_1.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 2234 Jul  8 19:37 cmd_2.sh*
```

Then I want to check in those permissions. But subversion sees no difference.

```
> svn status

<no response>
```

Subversion correctly sets the permissions for the files when the file is added to the repository, but how can I change them?

EDIT. I tried making a trivial change to the file along with changing its permissions to trick subversion into updating the file. Nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion does not manage filesystem permissions with two exceptions (see below). As a result, there are no changes to detect.

Exceptions:

- If the `svn:executable` property is set on a file, the executable bit will be set/changed on the filesystem by the client when checking out/updating.
- If the `svn:needs-lock` property is set on the file, the file will be set to read-only by the client until the user runs `svn lock <filename>`. It will be re-set to read-only upon commit (unless `--no-unlock` is specified) or `svn unlock <filename>` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `propset`

**[svn propset (pset, ps)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html)**

> On a Unix system, if you want a file to have the executable permission
>   set:
>
> `$ svn propset svn:executable ON somescript`
>    property 'svn:executable' set on 'somescript'